# Creating Dual Axis with "long" data

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to Tableau.  I have a dataset made up of year, has a measure that can be one of many values, and a corresponding value for that measure.  Example:

```
YEAR           MEASURE                 Value 
1988            Number of Cars           10
1989            Number of Cars           15
1988            Number of Peds           5
1989            Number of Peds           6
```

This is just an example data set.  But, I want to create bar char for Number of Cars and a line graph for Number of Peds.  How can this be done?  I was told I can do this without reorganizing the dataset (into a wide data set).

thanks
jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two calculated fields to separate Cars from Peds counts as follows:

```
if [measure name] = 'cars' then value end
```

Repeat for Peds. Then follow these instructions for dual axis. 
https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/multiplemeasures_dualaxes.html

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Would I do this in the Data Source view or the sheet?

Comment: Creating a [calculated field](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_create.html) is done in the sheet. As your new to tableau, I recommend taking a look at their resources to get up to speed on the basics.